# Send data with curl in Bash script: positional argument not working

Tags: json, bash, curl

Total noob in BASH. Trying to learn.
I have the following bash script to make an API request:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = "new_event" ]; then
    a='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'
    b=$2
    c='/events?access_token='
    d=$3
    path=$a$b$c$d

    echo $4

  OUTPUT="$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" $path -d $4 )"
  echo "${OUTPUT}"
fi
```

Positional arguments are 'new_event', calendarId, access token and json string.
If I run the script I get:

- first echo is the json string I pass as parameter in the call:

  ```
  ' {"guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": false, "location": "", "description": "TEST", "reminders": {"useDefault": false}, "start": {"dateTime": "2017-07-06T14:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"}, "end": {"dateTime": "2017-07-06T15:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"}, "guestsCanInviteOthers": false, "summary": "TEST", "status": "tentative", "attendees": []} '
  ```
- second echo gives me parsing error.

BUT, if I copy the echoed json string and replace $4 for it, everything works.

```
OUTPUT="$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" $path -d ' {"guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": false, "location": "", "description": "TEST", "reminders": {"useDefault": false}, "start": {"dateTime": "2017-07-06T14:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"}, "end": {"dateTime": "2017-07-06T15:00:00", "timeZone": "America/Sao_Paulo"}, "guestsCanInviteOthers": false, "summary": "TEST", "status": "tentative", "attendees": []} ' )"
```

Any hint why is it not working with the positional argument while it works if I paste it's content?

Thanks!

Comment: What is variable `$4`? It seems non-existent from the looks of it ...

Comment: Variable $4 is the forth positional argument i'm sending when i call the script, which is the json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the JSON string as a parameter, it assigns the content contained inside the single quote as a whole string but when you pass it to curl it was subjected to word splitting.

To show what it looks like here's a sample script to demonstrate it.

This script will receive the string and pass it to the second script.

```
#!/bin/bash
./params $1
```

This second script simulates what curl sees. It will print the number of parameters it receives.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
```

Guess what the output is:

```
27
```

To fix your issue and make it simpler, drop the outermost quote and quote everything inside the `$()`.

```
OUTPUT=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$path" -d "$4" )
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I am still trying to understand the behavior you mentioned. 27 is a very surprising result for a me (as a newbie). Yet, quoting the $4 didn't work out. Same behavior. I`ll try to get more detailed error adding parameters to curl.

Comment: My only guess is you are incorrectly quoting it. `bash` can't handle nested quote properly. You will need to post what you tried and the output when you run in verbose.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my friend. I`ve used single quotes instead of double. Now I'll work on understanding what happened. :) Thank you very much for your time.